T-Test to check if win/draw/loss results (home results) are independent from country/league where football games take place
I need to verify if win/draw/loss results (home results) are independent  from country/league where football games take place.
I have the following data table:
League              win draw loss
Premier League      193 96  91
LaLiga              194 95  91
Bundesliga          125 86  95
Serie A             108 65  67

I need to assign alpha of 0.05 significance to verify hypothesis.
Do I need to perform Shapiro tests for each vector (win/draw/loss), Kolmogorov-Smirnov test, or some embedded t.test in R?

I'd suggest to ask this question at Cross Validated.
